# How to get PID of a background process in PHP?

Tags: php, pid

```
php file.php &
```

How to get PID of the background process in `file.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the function `getmypid()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php

`posix_getpid()` seems to do the same thing...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpid.php

Comment: Hm. Well apparently they're not exactly the same :-) I'm glad one of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

[`getmypid()`](https://www.php.net/getmypid) does what you need.